# xss prevention with innerHtml and quotes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xss

I am trying to implement rule 1 in the [OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).  Rule 1 states the following characters should be encoded before inserting them into the body of a `<div>`:

```
 & --> &amp;
 < --> &lt;
 > --> &gt;
 " --> &quot;
 ' --> &#x27;
```

My goal is to insert the encoded characters into the DOM and have them render as their non encoded values.  However this does not seem to be possible, *with quotes*.

When you put either `&quot;` or `&#x27;` into the innerHTML of a div, the browser converts it back to `"` or `'`.

```js
document.getElementById("encodingNotWorking").innerHTML = "&amp; &gt; &lt; &quot;  &#x27; &#39; &#34;"

let domData = document.getElementById("encodingNotWorking").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("actualCharacters").innerText = domData;
```

```html
Encoded quote characters:
<div id = "encodingNotWorking">
</div>

Characters in the dom:
<div id = "actualCharacters">
</div>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLq03aug/))

How can I put the encoded entities (quotes) into the DOM, have them render as their non encoded values, and verify the encoded entities are actually in the DOM?

Comment: _"When you put either &quot; or &#x27; into the innerHTML of a div, the browser converts it back to " or '"_ - That's the exact reason why these entities exist o.O Display them as "normal" characters without their (context related) special meaning, like `<` in the DOM, or `"` in an attribute or ...

Comment: @Andreas The question is about the value inserted into the DOM, not what's being rendered.  The rendering is absolutely correct and what I want.  It's the value in the DOM itself that seems problematic, and a violation of XSS prevention best practices.

Comment: I still don't get it... You insert them as entities, they are displayed as "normal" characters (while still being entities, inspect the DOM and edit the HTML and you get the entities (where necessary)), and you the entities back when you grab the `.innerHTML`. So what's the problem?

Comment: @Andreas look at the fiddle.  You do not get the entities back for ' and " when looking at inner html.  How do you verify entities were put into the DOM?  How would a QA team verify that OWASPs rule 1 is being followed?

Comment: At that point, the quotes don't need to be encoded. That's only crucial when putting text into attributes, where quotes are obviously delimiters. Apparently the browser doesn't encode characters unnecessarily when reading them back.

Comment: @deceze yeah I actually reached out to OWASP for clarification given how the browser is behaving.  I am wondering if their cheat sheet is outdated.  It seems strange to have a recommendation that cannot be verified via any DOM inspection methods.  Any chance you have additional literature that verifies ' and " can skip encoding here?

Comment: Well, it's still solid advice, you can't go wrong encoding quotes too, and that way you don't need to consider special rules and conditions. It's just that the browser does something else when reading the value back, which is a different topic.